# : Unknown column in 'field list'

Tags: python, mysql

Was trying to set time and the other value to record table but showing: Unknown column 'time' in 'field list', I define time into VARCHAR(255) AND make the value specific to "e" because it is char type, can anyone here help me out with this, much appreciated

```py
import mysql.connector
import datetime

d = datetime.datetime.now()
e = d.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
  host="localhost",
  user="root",
  password="asd619248636",
  database="mydatabase"
)

mycursor = mydb.cursor()

mycursor.excute=("CREATE TABLE record (temperature FLOAT(20) , humidity FLOAT(20), time VARCHAR(255))")

#mycursor.execute("SHOW TABLES")

#for x in mycursor:
  #print(x) 

sql = "INSERT INTO record (temperature,humidity,time) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)"
val = (3.2,6.5,"e")
mycursor.execute(sql,val)
mydb.commit()

print(mycursor.rowcount, "record inserted.")
```

Answer (score 0):

I think ***time*** is a keyword in mysql according to [this](https://forums.mysql.com/read.php?101,665004,665004)

So in order to use it as a column name you will need to enclose it with backticks:

```
create_table_sql = "CREATE TABLE record (temperature FLOAT(20) , humidity FLOAT(20), `time` VARCHAR(255))"
sql = "INSERT INTO record (temperature,humidity,`time`) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)"
```

Comment: Have you deleted and re-created the table?